# C++11 faster std::vector iteration

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, iteration

Which one gives a better performance in terms of std::vector iteration: the newly introduced C++11 `for (auto &x: some_vector)` or `for (vector<type>::iterator it=some_vector.begin(); it != some_vector.end(); it++)` method?

Comment: and std::for_each with lambda expression.

Comment: It should be ++it, and the speed should be similar for both, as the c++11 syntax is basically sugar for the second. The for_each with lambda may be slower, depending on your compiler and if it can inline the lambda function.

Comment: The range based for loop also hoists the `end()` out of the loop.